# formatting data in csv format with awk

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

As I am new to this type of work, hence need some expert advice to achieve this task or any best way to get it done.

Below is the sample raw data which is pulled.

```
[root@dcconnect ~]# cat 11.csv
  uk1
  zone1-groupa   :   others=413/600(68.8%)   rhel=8/360(2.2%)   windows=74/300(24.7%)
  au1
  zone1-groupa   :   oracle-se2-rhel=0/60(0.0%)   others=166/240(69.2%)   rhel=4/360(1.1%)   windows=27/180(15.0%)
  de1
  zone1-groupa   :   oracle-se2-rhel=0/60(0.0%)   others=204/240(85.0%)   rhel=33/360(9.2%)   windows=106/180(58.9%)
  jp2
  zone1-groupa   :   others=641/780(82.2%)   rhel=223/420(53.1%)   windows=517/660(78.3%)
  zone1-groupb   :   oracle-se2=44/60(73.3%)   others=557/900(61.9%)   rhel=312/420(74.3%)   windows=163/600(27.2%)
  hk1
  zone1-groupa   :   oracle-se2-rhel=2/60(3.3%)   others=215/480(44.8%)   rhel=12/300(4.0%)   windows=172/360(47.8%)
  us1
  zone1-groupa   :   oracle-se2-rhel=1/60(1.7%)   others=325/480(67.7%)   rhel=5/300(1.7%)   windows=36/360(10.0%)
  zone1-groupb   :   others=76/480(15.8%)   rhel=1/480(0.2%)   windows=8/480(1.7%)
  sg1
  zone1-groupa   :   oracle-se2-rhel=19/60(31.7%)   others=390/480(81.3%)   rhel=84/360(23.3%)   windows=165/360(45.8%)
  zone1-groupb   :   others=81/480(16.9%)   rhel=33/480(6.9%)   windows=11/480(2.3%)
  jp1
  zone1-groupa   :   oracle-ee=12/60(20.0%)   others=4600/4680(98.3%)   rhel=914/1080(84.6%)   windows=2028/2100(96.6%)
  zone1-groupb   :   oracle-ee=9/60(15.0%)   oracle-se2=137/180(76.1%)   others=2409/2520(95.6%)   rhel=236/1440(16.4%)   windows=491/960(51.1%)
```

need help to get this in the below format or with ":" which can be separated in excel.

```
de1 zone1-groupa    oracle-se2-rhel 0   60  0.0%   
                    others  204 240 85.0%   
                    rhel    33  360 9.2%    
                    windows 106 180 58.9%
jp2 zone1-groupa    others  641 780 82.2%   
                    rhel    223 420 53.1%   
                    windows 517 660 78.3%
    zone1-groupb    oracle-se2  44  60  73.3%   
                    others  557 900 61.9%    
                    rhel    312 420 74.3%   
                    windows 163 600 27.2%
```

The data is very huge and need to collect it on daily 3 time. The raw data is generated in a Linux system.

Comment: LOL: "Please let me know if you need more information."

Comment: @ceving removed... that was just to get more information regarding my requirement.

Comment: Your input appears to be tab-separated, but not in any real sense CSV-compatible.  Proper CSV or TSV would have a fixed number of columns, no random lines with free-form labels.

Comment: The example output does not seem to match the example input.  Are you using unrelated examples or how does the input `others=209/240(87.1%)` map to `others  204 240 85.0%` for example?

Comment: Those are just example the value wont match. space separator can be used in excel format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following produces TSV (tab-separated) output matching your desired output (it won't align perfectly when printed in the console, but Excel should be able to read it with fields separated as intended):

```
awk '
  NF==1 { printf "%s", $1; next }
  { 
    printf "\t%s", $1
    sep="\t"
    for (i=3; i<=NF; ++i) {
      gsub("[=/()]", "\t", $i)
      printf "%s%s", sep, $i
      sep="\n\t\t"
    }
    printf "\n"
  }
' 11.csv
```